# Stata: "Weighted" uniform distribution (loaded dice)

Tags: stata, distribution

I'm doing some simulations in Stata to get around a problem with missing data for date of birth.

At the moment I'm generating a random day of birth in the interval [1, 365]:

```
gen BD = ceil(runiform()*365)
```

What I would like to have is that the frequency of birthdates in November and December (the interval [305, 365]) would be 95% lower than for the rest of the months.

Any idea how to implement this in Stata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like

```
tempname magic 
scalar `magic' = (61 * 0.05) / (304 + 61 * 0.05) 
gen BD = cond(runiform() <= `magic', ceil(304 + 61 * runiform()), ceil(304 * runiform()))
```

Here's a minimal test script:

```
clear 
set obs 100000
tempname magic 
scalar `magic' = (61 * 0.05) / (304 + 61 * 0.05) 
gen BD = cond(runiform() <= `magic', ceil(304 + 61 * runiform()), ceil(304 * runiform())) 
spikeplot BD
```

Comment: A very elegant solution that I was unable to find. Looking at the results, I think perhaps the OP misstated the requirement as "95% lower than" when "5% lower than" (equivalently, "95% of") was what was intended. I just don't see the opportunities for conception dropping quite that much in February and March.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski Indeed. I did a triple take at 95% lower but I take the OP at their word. It should be easy enough to see the principle and change the constant.

Comment: True, I actually misstated the requirement. What I will need is "95% of" the rest of the months. In any case, the solution works like a charm.